# Trusted Computing, iPad, Certifying Unmodified Apps

Tags: ipad, trusted-computing

Since Apple controls the entire hardware/software stack, is it possible to obtain the following (through some type of trusted computing):

- the hardware certifies that the software is genuine, non-jail broken iOS
- iOS certifies to *my server* that the app run is an unmodified app

What this achieve is as follows:

when my server sends out data, it is guaranteed that the data can only be used in the way I intend it to be used (since it's running my app unmodified, on an non-jail broken iOS).

This prevents things like a modified app which steals data being transmitted from the server to the client. I realize one could theoretically eavesdrop, but this can be eliminated via encryption.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Briefly, no.

You're talking about Trusted Computing concepts on a platform that does not support TC. IOS does not include anything near `Trusted Computing - Remote Attestation`. **It has no TPM**.

The chain of trust established by Apple chip merely tries to stop execution if the signature of the next element in the boot chain is invalid. If one thing fails (jailbroken), their's no real -effective- way of detecting it. It is very similar to Secure Boot introduce by Microsoft but it's very different then Trusted Computing which `attest` which version of the system it is currently running.

With Trusted Computing, the TPM store the measurements (PCRs) of the system boot (SRTM). At boot, the first thing executed (CRTM - the only thing we really need to trust implicitly) will start the chain by measuring the BIOS, send the measure to the TPM (in a PCR) and pass execution to it (the BIOS). Then the BIOS does the same thing for the next element in the boot chain.

The measurements stored in the PCRs can then be used to encrypt or decrypt information (SEAL/UNSEAL operations) depending on the environment loaded in memory.

The TPM does not take action on the measurements (good or bad). The idea is not to restrain what can be loaded but to being able to know what environment is loaded on the platform. If something has been modified, the TPM will not contain the proper PCRs values and the UNSEAL operation (decrypt using PCRs as the key) will not work.

In the case of Remote Attestation, we're talking about the QUOTE operation. It's basically the same thing then SEAL but uses other keys to make sure the evaluating party can validate the attestation is really coming from a real/compliant TPM.

Sure, a system could use the SEAL operation to protect a secret used to decrypt the operating system and thus produce -in some way- the same effect as secure boot.

For more info, see my other posts.